# twisted deferToThread tcp connections

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

I am new to twisted, trying to write my first application, I am actually stuck with this problem:

I have a main thread that loads a bunch of modules to run, each one of thoses modules are located on a remote server and available through a tcp connection, here what the module run code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import struct

from twisted.internet import endpoints
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.spread import pb
from txapp.core import get_modules

from txmod.spread import EnvelopeSpreadReceiver


@inlineCallbacks
def listen(reactor):
    modules = yield get_modules()

    for mod in modules:
        endpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, 'tcp:%d:%s' %
                                              (int(mod.get('module_server_port') or 0),
                                               socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', mod.get('module_server_ipaddr'))),))
        endpoint.listen(pb.PBServerFactory(EnvelopeSpreadReceiver()))
        print 'PBServerFactory starting on %s:%d for module %s' % (
            socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', mod.get('module_server_ipaddr'))),
            int(mod.get('module_server_port')),
            mod.get('module_name'))


def main():
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    listen(reactor)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A given server *may* run multiple modules on different ports, but generally it will be : **1 server, 1 module**

The main server which runs the application will try to connect to each module, run code and expect a result (success or not).

I am struggling on how to make this code non blocking: the tcp connection can hang if the server have trouble to respond, so should I put each module tcp connection on a separate thread with `deferToThread` ?

The main application will handle millions of requests per day, so it should be completely non blocking.

Is this the correct way of handle this ? Can someone point me to the right direction on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twisted's event-loop APIs are not thread safe, as covered by [Twisted's threading documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/core/howto/threading.html).  This means you absolutely cannot call `deferToThread` to handle a connection; it would crash if you tried.

A waiting TCP connection will not cause your event loop to get stuck though; the APIs for sending and receiving data to a connection are already non-blocking. So I don't think you have a problem to solve here, it's already solved for you.